# Kernel problem when using PyQtGraph on Spyder

Tags: python, pyqt, kernel, spyder, pyqtgraph

I have to have a common issue with PyQtGraph when I use it in Spyder 5.2.2 (and Python 3.9).
I'm running one of the given example codes seen below:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

plot = pg.plot()
plot.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: MultiPlotSpeedTest')
plot.setLabel('bottom', 'Index', units='B')

nPlots = 100
nSamples = 500
curves = []
for idx in range(nPlots):
    curve = pg.PlotCurveItem(pen=(idx,nPlots*1.3))
    plot.addItem(curve)
    curve.setPos(0,idx*6)
    curves.append(curve)

plot.setYRange(0, nPlots*6)
plot.setXRange(0, nSamples)
plot.resize(600,900)

rgn = pg.LinearRegionItem([nSamples/5.,nSamples/3.])
plot.addItem(rgn)


data = np.random.normal(size=(nPlots*23,nSamples))
ptr = 0
lastTime = time()
fps = None
count = 0
def update():
    global curve, data, ptr, plot, lastTime, fps, nPlots, count
    count += 1

    for i in range(nPlots):
        curves[i].setData(data[(ptr+i)%data.shape[0]])

    ptr += nPlots
    now = time()
    dt = now - lastTime
    lastTime = now
    if fps is None:
        fps = 1.0/dt
    else:
        s = np.clip(dt*3., 0, 1)
        fps = fps * (1-s) + (1.0/dt) * s
    plot.setTitle('%0.2f fps' % fps)
    #app.processEvents()  ## force complete redraw for every plot
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

The problem is that when I shut down the app's window (clicking x), Spyder's kernel doesn't stop running. I can restart it manually once, but if I run the app a second time then the kernel is completely stuck. I have to kill Spyder and restart to be able to attempt running code again.

I seem to understand from googling the problem that it's because Spyder itself is a QApplication and running another one causes conflicts and confusion. Like the Kernel keeps variables it's not supposed to.
However none of the solutions proposed to fix this on PyQt seems to work on PyQtGraph !

Does anyone here uses PyQtGraph on Spyder ?

How do You set it up to run smoothly ?

Thank You

Comment: Not totally sure if you already checked the Spyder wiki but just in case: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-run-PyQt-applications-within-Spyder

Comment: @DanielAlthviz I did, but PyQtGraph uses QtGui.QApplication instead of  QtWidgets.QApplication and so it doesn't seem to work. Not sure why it behaves differently.

Comment: I checked locally with Spyder 5.2.2 and I had to change the graphic backend preference to `Inline` at `Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics > Graphics backend`. Also, checked with Spyder 5.3.3 but in that case I was able to run multiple times the code regardless of the graphics backend. Maybe changing the graphics backend or updating Spyder could help you?